# Error 401 en sql server en peticion post stored procedure en la segunda url?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, http-post

alguien ha realizado un sp con peticiones post en 2 urls, yo estoy realizando una pero la primera url me devuelve el json pero la 2da url no me devuelve el json me envia un vacio, en si lo estoy realizando con sql server T-SQL
he estado investigando como solucionar este error pero no doy con la solucion, e incluso ya probe las 2 urls con postman y si ejecuta bien lo que yo me pregunto que estare haciendo mal

[![Response de la 1er data json][1]][1]

--- CODIGO ---

```
 EXEC sp_json_pycca_restAPI
    ALTER PROCEDURE sp_json_pycca_restAPI
    as
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @postData2 NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
    --DECLARE @responseText2 NVARCHAR(2000);
    --DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE @token INT;
    DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @url2 NVARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE @cookie NVARCHAR(2000);
    
    --DECLARE @Authorization NVARCHAR(200);
    --DECLARE @cookie VARCHAR(8000);
    
    /*#1 BLOQUE LOGIN */
    --SET @authHeader = 'BASIC 0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
    SET @cookie = 'HTTP_SECURITY_COOKIE=cd779845-b194-42c9-b40c-7b77b85deccc; path=/; secure; httponly; SameSite=Strict'
    SET @contentType =  'application/json'
    SET @postData =  
    '{
        "Mail": "prueba@gmail.com",
        "Password": "12345"
    }'
    SET @url = 'https://qa-tools.linkonex.com/rest/CES.Core.Security.IAuthenticationServices/Login'
    
    -- ABRIMOS LA CONEXION
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
    
    --ENVIAMOS LA RESPUESTA 
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType, 'Cookie', @cookie
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;
    --EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'AddHeader', NULL, 'Cookie', @cookie
    
    -- MANEJAMOS LA RESPUESTA
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;
    
    -- OBSERVAMOS LA RESPUESTA 
    PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
    PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;
    select @responseText as Resultado_Json_Login
    
    -- CERRAMOS LA CONEXION 
    EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
    --go
```

[![Cookies como un header en postman][2]][2]

segun veo que es por la cookie y no se como hacer que traiga el 2do json y no encuentro la solucion
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Xma.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiBHz.png

Comment: Haz intentado con el `WAITFOR`? La primera línea del SP tiene que ser el WAITFOR para esperar un tiempo determinado para la ejecución de las consultas siguientes, creo que te puede funcionar.

Comment: Sería útil ver el código TSQL para poder dar una respuesta sobre qué estás haciendo mal. Ve a [edit] y añade un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que estás intentando

Comment: Ah! solo para aclarar, no es obligatorio el WAITFOR en ningún SP ni en ninguna consulta, decía que "tiene que ser la primera línea del SP" refiriéndome a tu caso en específico.

Comment: acabo de agregar el codigo, pero lo mismo me sirve para la 2da url, ademas en el postman como dije probe las 2 urls y salen bien, segun vi es por la cookie que la estan enviando como header ? alguna solucion para eso